# componentDidCatch second parameter not type compatible with function being called from within

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0, react-lifecycle, react-error-boundary

I have a standard `componentDidCatch` in my component, which is typed like below and calls an external Logging library from within:

```
  componentDidCatch(error: Error, info: React.ErrorInfo) {
    Logger.logErrorMessage(error.message, info);
  }
```

However the 3rd party logging library `logErrorMessage` function is typed something like:

```
type ArbitraryValue = undefined | string | number | boolean | ArbitraryObject;

interface ArbitraryObject {
  [p: string]: ArbitraryValue;
}

...


logErrorMessage(message: string, info: ArbitraryObject): void;
```

The TS error message displays the following

```
.../ErrorBoundary.tsx:38:82 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'ErrorInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArbitraryObject'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'ErrorInfo'.

38     Logger.logErrorMessage(error, info);
                                     ~~~~
```

What is the best way to get my `info` parameter of componentDidCatch to adhere to the ArbitraryObject interface of logErrorMessage? Optimally without having to change the Logger library source.

Comment: Suggestion: just have `ArbitraryObject` extend `React.ErrorInfo`? The latter only appears to have a single property member named `componentStack`.

Comment: `ArbitraryObject` is part of the `Logger` library that I only consume.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I don't think the compiler will be happy with an `as ArbitraryObject` cast, so the only other thing I can think of is to not pass `info` directly and create a new object to erase the `React.ErrorInfo` interface (i.e. pass `{ ...info }` instead).